# Python NameError: global name 'Thread' is not defined

Tags: python

I made file called thread.py and if I want to import it, it doesn't work. When I use a filename like cheese.py it works fine

```
import json
from thread import Thread
class Board:
        name = ""
        shortcode = ""
        threads = []
        url = ""
        api_url = ""
        json = ""

        def __init__(self, board, api_url, json):
                self.shortcode = board
                self.api_url = api_url
                self.json = json
                self.__getPosts()

        def __getPosts(self):
                i = 0
                for thread in self.json[0]['threads']:
                        thread = Thread()
                        self.threads[i] = thread
                        i+=1
```

thread.py

```
class Thread:
        def __init__(self):
                i = 1
```

Comment: changing thread.py filename will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A built-in module with the name [`thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) already exists.

```
>>> import thread
>>> thread
<module 'thread' (built-in)>
```

When you are trying to import using `from thread import Thread` it is trying to search for the attribute named `Thread` which does not exists in the built-in [`thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) module.

```
>>> hasattr(thread, 'Thread')
False
```

When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path).

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) is initialized from these locations:

- The directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
- [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
- The installation-dependent default.

For more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

It is recommended that you use a user defined module name that is different than the built-in module name.

Comment: Is it possible to override this so I don't need to rename my class?

Comment: You don't need to rename your class, you have to rename your module `thread.py` to something like `mythread.py`  or something relevant to you .

Answer (score -1):

Python 3 has a  built in module [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) that has a class called [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)

which is causing the conflict, so consider renaming your file to something else.